# Removing an SKSpriteNode by name

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an object called "color" and I give each spawned "color" a name such as:

"red"

"blue"

"green"

I want to know how can I remove the object "color" by its `.name` extension using `removeFromParent()` in an if statement?

Basically the spawning code produces "red", "blue" or "green" then I want to have an if statement that runs when the user uses the keyboard.

```
if str?.lowercaseString == color.name {
      "remove the color with that name extension".removeFromParent()
```

basically I want to remove the color with the name extension (red, blue or green) that matched the "subject"variable in the if statement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you already have a color object that you are comparing and you already have something to compare it to (subject), you have all the pieces you need. You just don't include the name property when removing from parent.

```
if subject == color.name {
    color.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ron! I was thinking too much about it. Cheers!

Comment: It's funny, because we've all been there. Most times the problems are that we over complicate things

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a SKNode, such as SKSpriteNode with the `.removeFromParent()` method. Make sure you're not trying to remove something else, since it won't work.

```
if str?.lowercaseString == color.name {
      color.removeFromParent() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant something different. Question edited to explain better! :)

Comment: What is you subject variable in your if statement?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't quite clear enough. I am using a keyboard.